# Cosmos DB - slower performance issue

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

All these days, in our cosmos db we had non partitioned collections & recently moved our app data to partitioned collections to overcome 10gb cap on single partition.

Few things we have noticed right after **introducing partitions**.

1. ResourceResponse.ContentLocation property returns null. (usually it returns collection path like "dbs/developmentdb/colls/accountmodel" as value with non partitioned collections)
2. For **"GetAll"** query (provided same data maintained in both partitioned and non partitioned collections)

   - RUs went up (from 400RUs to 750RUs)
   - Slower response time

For your reference included below, the code used. Appreciate any of your suggestions to reduce RUs & improve response time (OR) these all are overheads of moving to partitioned collection? please suggest

Sample code used:

```
                var docClient = await _documentClient; 
                var docDb = await _documentDatabase;   
                var docCollection = await _documentCollection;

                var queryFeed = new FeedOptions()
                {
                    MaxItemCount = -1,
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1,
                    EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
                };

                var documentCollectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(docDb.Id, docCollection.Id);

                IDocumentQuery<T> query = docClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(documentCollectionUri, queryFeed).AsDocumentQuery();

                while (query.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    var page = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
                    result.AddRange(page);

                    _rULogHelper.LogFromFeedResponse(page, docDb.Id, docCollection.Id, DBOperationType.GET.ToString()); //custom logging related code
                }
```

Comment: For query performance issues, this article might help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-query-performance#log-query-metrics

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta, Thanks for your reference to msdn general recommendations. By looking in to above posted documentdb related code, do you find anything that is missing or anything that can be modified/included to improve response time & to reduce RUs? please suggest.

Comment: if I ran above posted code against non partitioned collection ResourceResponse.ContentLocation returns value as  "dbs/devdb/colls/customermodel" which is expected but against partitioned collection ResourceResponse.ContentLocation always returns null. Any reason?please confirm. Note: Data migrated from non partitioned to partitioned collection using change feed.